# How to sort a data in txt file?

Tags: php, text-files, fwrite

I have generated txt file. How to sort the lines in it by first number before `|` ?

It have structure like:

```
1|5
4|7
2|3
3|1
```

I try like this, but it's show error. Full code:

```
$str='';
    foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $num => $answer) {
        $str.="$num|".rtrim($answer)."\r\n";
    }
$data = explode("\n",$str);
sort($data,SORT_NUMERIC);
$date=date('y-m-d_H-i-s');
$fp=fopen("output/".$date."_out.txt", "w+");
$write=fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
if ($write) echo 'Done!';
```

Comment: `$data` is an array at the time of the `fwrite` call, whilst `fwrite` requires a string. Try: `$write = fwrite($fp, implode("\n",$data));`

Comment: Thank you! It's work! But before first line and after second line added some simbol. How to remowe it?

Comment: This is: http://s017.radikal.ru/i409/1110/5b/4aa44ed12d42.bmp

Comment: Ah, change all instances of `"\n"` to `"\r\n"` - I didn't realise you were using Windows. You may also want to `trim($str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = trim(file_get_contents('file'));
$data = explode("\n",$data);
sort($data,SORT_NUMERIC);
$data = implode("\n",$data);
```

Comment: Thank's but not work( `Error: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string`

Comment: You're trying to write an array to the file. Try `file_put_contents('filename',implode("\n",$data));`

Answer (score 3):

```
$file = file('path/to/file');
sort($file, SORT_NUMERIC);
fwrite('path/to/file', join("\n", $file));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the fastest and most elegant solution that I have found, when I had the same problem.
If you're on Linux (with exec allowed in PHP configuration) you can do the following (provided you want to sort files numerically):

```
exec("sort -n " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
```

Basically, execute bash command **sort** that sorts the lines in a file numerically.
If you want to keep the data in the original file do this:

```
exec("sort -n " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
exec("rm " . $pathToOriginalFile);
exec("mv " . $pathToSortedFile . " " . $pathToOriginalFile);
```

If you want an alphabetical sort just exclude -n (--numeric-sort) option.

```
exec("sort " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
```

For me the command took about 3 seconds to sort 10 million lines in the file on the server.

You can find more about sort here http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usort.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: Five years later, and I wish I could upvote this twice. :)